# How to change a position of a table cell dynamically? or Is it possible?

Tags: c#, html, css

I'm trying to figure out something here but not sure whether it's good code practice or if it's possible or not.

I want to change a position of a table cell dynamically.

This is the current code.

```
            <td style="padding-top: 12px; vertical-align: top;" runat="server" id="HomeScreen">
                <div class="uc-home-head" style="width: 254px; height: 30px; background: transparent url('/images/home_totalHeader_twitter.png');
                    margin-bottom: 15px; font-weight: bolder;">
                    <div style="padding-left: 5px; float: left; margin-top: 10px;"><div style="line-height:10px;">INKWRX Updates</div>
                    </div>
                </div>                    
                <div style="clear: both;">
                </div>
                <a data-widget-id="345496112829980672" width="254px" data-chrome="noheader nofooter transparent"
                    class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/destinywireless" data-show-replies="false"></a>
            </td>


         if (CurrentUser.HomeScreenReport)
            {
                ucErrors.Parent.Controls.Remove(ucErrors);
                ActivityBar1.Parent.Controls.Remove(ActivityBar1);

                tblTable1.Controls.Remove(tblTable1.Rows[0]);

                HomeScreen.Style.Add("bottom", "80px");
            }
```

After removing the controls, I want to re-position the table cell.
When I add `style="position: absolute;"` in the *HTML* style and `HomeScreen.Style.Add("bottom", "80px");` in `c#`, the whole row messed up.

Thank you.